# how to add a image in wrapped site in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I wrapped a website into ionic app here.I just wish to add a image before it takes me to the respective site and the home.html is an empty page.I already have splash screens.I don't have anything in home.html so it shows a white screen which is awkward so i added in template area such as "`<p>...loading please wait</p>`" as it takes the time to load the URL. when i exit the app it goes to home.html and exit the app.So i wish to add a image in that area so that it looks full. Any help would be appreciated.

**home.ts**

```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';
   import { NavController ,Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
   import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';
   import { DocumentViewer, DocumentViewerOptions } from '@ionic- 
   native/document-viewer';
   @Component({
   template : "<p>....Loading please wait<img>"
    })
   export class HomePage {
   constructor(private iab: InAppBrowser,public platform: Platform, private 
   document : DocumentViewer ) {
   platform.ready().then(() => {
   let browser = this.iab.create('http://study.bfa.org/','_blank', 
   {zoom:'no',location:'no'});
       browser.show();
   });
   }
  }
```

Comment: `<p>....Loading please wait<img>` what.... what's going on there?

Comment: Actually !! i solved it by myself . I did a silly mistake ..its a wrapper app,it loads and goes to the respective URL which i mentioned in "InAppBrowser"